# Como convertir un vector de enteros a texto sin perder los ceros a izquierda en MatLab

Tags: matlab

Tengo un vector de numeros en binarios `inf=[01000101 01110011 01110100 01100101]` pero al hacer la conversion a texto, segun la documentacion de matlab recomienda bien sea utilizar int2str o num2str para mi caso lo utilice asi `infEnv=num2str(inf)`

```
inf=[00001101 01110011 01110100 01100101]
infEnv=num2str(inf)
```

el resultado que me arroja es

```
 inf =
   1.1010e+03   1.1100e+06   1.1101e+06   1.1001e+06

infEnv = 1101  1110011  1110100  1100101
```

Si ven en en los dos casos me omite los ceros que tiene a la izquierda, ¿como hago para que no los omitas y salgan tal cual como se los envio?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba agregando el argumento `%8d` luego de la conversión del número, donde el número 8 indica los digitos a mantener.

Para el ejemplo que publicas puede utilizar el siguiente ciclo for:

```matlab
infEnv = num2str(inf(1), '%08d');

for i = inf(2:end)
    infEnv = [infEnv ' ' num2str(i, '%08d')];
end

infEnv
```

Saludos